# Trace reverse tensor/matrix operation "carrying through" an operator

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

For some second rank tensor $h_{\mu\nu}$ on a Riemannian manifold with metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, one can write the trace-reverse of it as: $\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}=h_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}h$, where $h=h_{\mu}^{\mu}$, summation implied. I'm wondering what the conditions are such that, for an operator (let's use the Laplacian for example).

$$\nabla^{2}\left(\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}\right)=\overline{\left(\nabla^{2}\left(h_{\mu\nu}\right)\right)}$$

i.e the trace reverse carries through the operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I have put together so far, please tell me what you think:

For some linear operator L
  that doesn't change the indices of $h_{\mu\nu}$

$$L(\bar{h}_{\mu\nu})=L(h_{\mu\nu})-L(\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}(g^{\alpha\beta}h_{\alpha\beta}))$$

$$\bar{\{L(h_{\mu\nu}})\}=L(h_{\mu\nu})-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}(Tr[Lh_{\alpha\beta}])$$

Then:

$$L(g_{\mu\nu}(g^{\alpha\beta}h_{\alpha\beta}))=g_{\mu\nu}(Tr[Lh_{\alpha\beta}])$$

$$L(g_{\mu\nu})g^{\alpha\beta}h_{\alpha\beta}+g_{\mu\nu}L(g^{\alpha\beta})h_{\alpha\beta}+g_{\mu\nu}g^{\alpha\beta}[Lh_{\alpha\beta}]=g_{\mu\nu}(Tr[Lh_{\alpha\beta}])$$

Then, the reverse trace operation carries through if:

$$g^{\mu\nu}L(g_{\mu\nu})g^{\alpha\beta}h_{\alpha\beta}+L(g^{\alpha\beta})h_{\alpha\beta}+g^{\alpha\beta}[Lh_{\alpha\beta}]=(Tr[Lh_{\alpha\beta}])$$